D3 Projection has black border, causes country fills to be impossible
I am currently trying to setup a D3 Map with PIXI. For some reason, when using d3.geoMercator with data from https://www.geoboundaries.org/. I get this border around my map:

When having all my countries outlined this is fine, but I am wanting to highlight countries in different colours. As soon as I try any form of fill it fills the entire screen.
I can't tell whether this is an issue with my data or d3.geoMercator. I saw some questions where the answer was to not use geoMercator, but without any projection my map data renders incorrectly. If anyone can explain how to remove this border it would be much appreciated, this problem has had me stumped for a while now.
Code that handles projection:
    #computeProjections() {
        if (!this.cachedProjections) {
            const projection = d3.geoMercator()
                .scale(this.transform.k / (2 * Math.PI))
                .translate([this.transform.x, this.transform.y]);

            const path = d3.geoPath(projection);

            this.cachedProjections = { projection, path };
        }
        return this.cachedProjections;
    }

    async #renderCanvas() {
        if (this.renderingCanvas) {
            return;
        }
        this.renderingCanvas = true;

        const { projection, path } = this.#computeProjections();

        let geoJsonQuality;
        if (this.transform.k < (1 << 11)) {
            geoJsonQuality = "geoJsonLow";
        } else if (this.transform.k < (1 << 13)) {
            geoJsonQuality = "geoJsonMedium";
        } else {
            geoJsonQuality = "geoJson";
        }

        for (const country of Object.values(this.countries)) {
            const geoJson = country[geoJsonQuality];
            const visible = this.#isCountryVisible(geoJson, projection);

            if (visible) {
                country.graphics.clear();
                country.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2, 0x000000);
                path.context(country.graphics);
                country.graphics.beginPath();
                path(geoJson);
                country.graphics.closePath();
                country.graphics.stroke();
            } else {
                country.graphics.clear();
            }
        }
        this.renderingCanvas = false;
    }



Almost certainly a winding issue, see here

@AndrewReid Brilliant, I would've never found this. Using turf fixed my issue thank you :)
